# Excel - Returning multiple unique queries from a range based on non-unique criteria, ie similar rank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, ranking-functions

I am stumped to find the right formula to accurately return the top three ranked outcomes from a range in all scenarios. When the rankings are not equal things are always fine, 1,2,3,4,5. However when the top 2 or 3 outcomes are tied for first place, say 1,1,1,4,5, I cannot find the right formula to return all top 3 accurately.

Ranking of Locations
[image: Ranking of Locations]

The array 'Helper' formula range at E3:E6 works perfectly with 'Top 3' range at F3:F6 so the rank sorting logic is working fine.

Helper Arrays
[image: Helper Arrays]

Top 3 reference Range
[image: Top 3 reference range]

The final step of creating a 'Top 3 List' range at G3:G6 is where it goes wrong. I have tried many variants, including array formulae which I am new to, but none work. The best so far is a MATCH & SMALL combo but not good with duplicates. (see below)

Top 3 - List' formula not grabbing all 3 #1 locations
[image: 'Top 3 - List' formula not grabbing all 3 #1 locations]

Please if someone knows a formula which will return an accurate 'Top 3 list' even when there are duplicate rankings? Thanks!

PS: This is my first request post. Stackoverflow has helped me MANY times

[No duplicates -Everything is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KRXw.jpg)

[One duplicate score - 1st and 2nd top are actually #1 twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx7Xq.jpg)

[Two duplicate scores - 1st, 2nd and 3rd top are actually #1 3x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl9iW.jpg)

Comment: can you post a picture of expected results??

Comment: What should the results be if 4 or more are tied for top 3?

Comment: This question is really about the simple stuff at the end: Taking whatever output is at F3:F6 (Top 3) and making a proper list at G3:G6. I added the other information for reference. I will add a few more screenshots of when it looks like there are two duplicates etc. Regarding 4 ties for top, RANK.EQ will do its job but I'll only be able to list 3 of them which will be the 3 highest on the list guess. That scenario will be exceedingly rare for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer will return the top three results in the order they appear in your list.  It may even be possible to eliminate the helper column but I did not test that far.  I reordered your list so that it was not simply grabbing the first three rows.  Otherwise it would be as simple as sorting your list and linking to the top three lines.

#### Helper column to grab the top three scores

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$4:$C$8,ROW(A1))
```

It assumes your data is in B4:C8.  Copy the formula down until you have it in three rows.  Aggregate with 14 will sort you list from largest to smallest.  Row(A1) will return the first value in the sorted list.  when its copied down it will increase to row(A2) so it will return the second value in the sorted list and so on.

#### Matching the sorted score to the names

This assumes your top three list of scores is in E4:E6

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$4:$C$8)/($C$4:$C$8=E4),COUNTIF($E$4:E4,E4)))
```

Its finding all the rows numbers that match the number in your sorted top three list.  When there is a repeat, it advances to the next row number in the matching list due to the countif.  The row number is then passed to INDEX which in turn pulls the name.

[image: POC]

Comment: Works perfect !!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're referencing the Top 3 column, which will always be "1" if there are tied. Shouldn't you be using the Helper column for that?

```
=OFFSET($A$2,MATCH(SMALL($C$3:$C$7,E4),$C$3:$C$7,0),0)
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. It might not be elegant but Helper is there to make a reliable functional Top 3 range which is accurate as it stands. As there are 3 locations tied for highest score the Top 3 range shows 1,1,1 which is correct. It goes wrong after that when using 'Top 3' to create 'Top 3 List'

Comment: Have you tried using the code? I basically just changed your reference from the Top 3 Rankings to the Helper column, because you already have the logic to sort the rankings, so it should populate your list properly even though there's a tie.

Comment: In your comment above you indicate using the relative reference to E4 (helper) instead of F4 (Top 3). Do you indicate using the same relative reference down the whole Top 3 list range from E3 to E6 instead of F3 to F6? If this is true than the output of 'Top 3 List' will be the first #1 ranked item on the list followed by rank 4 and 5 which is not right. When the 3 highest are equal they all share a #1 ranking and all the distinct #1 locations need to be listed without duplicates. Are you suggesting a different formula syntax on G3 as compared to G4 and G5?

Comment: Might be easier to share the sheet but don't if that possible here